# Repeated measures ANOVA - degrees of freedom

Tags: r, repeated-measures

I'm studying repeated measures ANOVAs, found this example online and can't understand how are the df calculated. What would be the mathematical expression for calculating both df values in this example?

```
data(obk.long, package = "afex")

# estimate mixed ANOVA on the full design:
aov_car(value ~ treatment * gender + Error(id/(phase*hour)), 
        data = obk.long, observed = "gender")


# the three calls return the same ANOVA table:
# Anova Table (Type 3 tests)
# 
# Response: value
#                         Effect          df   MSE         F  ges p.value
# 1                    treatment       2, 10 22.81    3.94 + .198    .055
# 2                       gender       1, 10 22.81    3.66 + .115    .085
# 3             treatment:gender       2, 10 22.81      2.86 .179    .104
# 4                        phase 1.60, 15.99  5.02 16.13 *** .151   <.001
# 5              treatment:phase 3.20, 15.99  5.02    4.85 * .097    .013
# 6                 gender:phase 1.60, 15.99  5.02      0.28 .003    .709
# 7       treatment:gender:phase 3.20, 15.99  5.02      0.64 .014    .612
# 8                         hour 1.84, 18.41  3.39 16.69 *** .125   <.001
# 9               treatment:hour 3.68, 18.41  3.39      0.09 .002    .979
# 10                 gender:hour 1.84, 18.41  3.39      0.45 .004    .628
# 11       treatment:gender:hour 3.68, 18.41  3.39      0.62 .011    .641
# 12                  phase:hour 3.60, 35.96  2.67      1.18 .015    .335
# 13        treatment:phase:hour 7.19, 35.96  2.67      0.35 .009    .930
# 14           gender:phase:hour 3.60, 35.96  2.67      0.93 .012    .449
# 15 treatment:gender:phase:hour 7.19, 35.96  2.67      0.74 .019    .646
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Those degrees of freedom are the result of applying the Greenhouse–Geisser correction (Greenhouse & Geisser, 1959), which is the default correction applied by aov_car, as far as I know.

In Salkind (2010), Hervé Abdi states that:

> In addition to the usual assumptions of normality of the error and
> homogeneity of variance, the F test for repeated-measurement designs
> assumes a condition called sphericity. Intuitively, this condition
> indicates that the ranking of the subjects does not change across
> experimental treatments. This is equivalent to stating that the
> population correlation (computed from the subjects’ scores) between
> two treatments is the same for all pairs of treatments. This condition
> implies that there is no interaction between the subject factor and
> the treatment. If the sphericity assumption is not valid, then the F
> test becomes too liberal (i.e., the proportion of rejections of the
> null hypothesis is larger than the α level when the null hypothesis is
> true).

As per [this link](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/sphericity-statistical-guide.php):

> The degree to which sphericity is present, or not, is represented by a
> statistic called epsilon (ε). An epsilon of 1 (i.e., ε = 1) indicates
> that the condition of sphericity is exactly met. The further epsilon
> decreases below 1 (i.e., ε < 1), the greater the violation of
> sphericity. Therefore, you can think of epsilon as a statistic that
> describes the degree to which sphericity has been violated. The lowest
> value that epsilon (ε) can take is called the lower-bound estimate.
> Both the Greenhouse-Geisser and the Huynd-Feldt procedures attempt to
> estimate epsilon (ε), albeit in different ways (it is an estimate
> because we are dealing with samples, not populations). For this
> reason, the estimates of sphericity (ε) tend to always be different
> depending on which procedure is used. By estimating epsilon (ε), all
> these procedures then use their sphericity estimate (ε) to correct the
> degrees of freedom for the F-distribution.

The calculation of ε is rather long, and one would need to paste here a series of formulas and notations to fully reproduce the logic, so I just refer you to the quoted sources.

You can see what ε values R is using to perform the correction through the summary command:

```
b<-aov_car(value ~ treatment * gender + Error(id/(phase*hour)), 
        data = obk.long, observed = "gender")
b
summary(b)
```

The degrees of freedom you see in your question are the result of multiplying the original degrees of freedom by ε.

If you want to see those original degrees of freedom, you can specify that you don't want any correction:

```
c<-aov_car(value ~ treatment * gender + Error(id/(phase*hour)), 
           data = obk.long, observed = "gender", anova_table = list(correction = "none"))
c
```

Only the degrees of freedom corresponding to within subjects variables will be corrected by epsilon, as Vonesh et al. (1997) state:

> Box (1954a, 1954b) suggested adjusting the numerator and denominator
> degrees of freedom for the within-units F tests by multiplying the by
> the lower bound of e, namely, 1/(p-1).

**For more detail, I highly recommend the excellent book by Howell (2013)**. The repeated-measures designs chapter is very friendly and it describes what to do when you have either 1) two between-subjects + 1 within-subjects factors design or 2) two within-subjects + 1 between-subjects factors design. **Page 481** shows the formulas to obtain the degrees of freedom for the first design, and **page 484** shows the formulas for the second design.

Finally, [this link](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/the-anova-table-ss-and-df-in-two-way-anova/) contains and example of how to calculate degrees of freedom.

Sources:

- Box, G. E. P. (1954a). Some Theorems on Quadratic Forms Applied in
  the Study of Analysis of Variance Problems, I. Effect of Inequality
  of Variance in the One-Way Classification. The Annals of Mathematical
  Statistics, 25(2), 290–302. https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177728786
- Box, G. E. P. (1954b). Some Theorems on Quadratic Forms Applied in
  the Study of Analysis of Variance Problems, II. Effects of Inequality
  of Variance and of Correlation Between Errors in the Two-Way
  Classification. The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 25(3),
  484–498. https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177728717
- Greenhouse, S. W., & Geisser, S. (1959). On methods in the analysis
  of profile data. Psychometrika, 24(2), 95–112.
  https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02289823
- Howell, D. C. (2013). Statistical Methods for Psychology (8th ed). Wadsworth Cengage Learning.
- Salkind, N. J. (Ed.). (2010). Encyclopedia of research design. SAGE
  Publications.
- Vonesh, E. F., Chinchilli, V. M., & NetLibrary, I. (1997). Linear and
  nonlinear models for the analysis of repeated measurements. M.
  Dekker.

The specific chapter from Salkind (2010) is available [here](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7EHerve/abdi-GreenhouseGeisser2010-pretty.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! But for example, in the first row, the df1= 2 and df2 = 10 for the 'treatment' variable don't change with the correction, so do you know how these are calculated? Specifically, how do they reach the df2 = 10?

Comment: The first row's degrees of freedom are not changed because they are not multiplied by epsilon, as they belong to a between-subjects variable (only the within-subjects variable are corrected, and the interactions that involve them). I expanded the references, the specific math and justifications can be found there.

Comment: I noticed you posted this question about repeated measures anova's df both here in StackOverflow and in StackExchange. I suggest you to close the duplicated question in Stackexchange first (as much as I would like to answer it in stackexchange too and get those points) and then ask for your second question (the one involving Reality and Round) to be reopened, in order to get a more detailed answer there by somebody more familiar with that situation.

Comment: Your site was helpful! Thank you! But still one remaining doubt - how did they arrive to 45 value if they had 49 subjects and two within-subject factors with 2 levels each (plus two between-subject factors with 2 levels each)?

Comment: I'm not sure. But anyway that calculation belongs to your question in StackExchange and should be adressed there. StackOverflow's objective is to talk about the code used, while StackExchange deals with the math specificities. You can get some math detail on StackOverflow and some coding detail on StackExchange, but those are just welcomed extras, not the main idea of the sites. I think this question has been sufficiently answered and you now have the necessary bibliography to go check the formulas and calculate. StackExchange will be of help to support that detailed calculation.

Comment: By the way, the afex package is calling the anova function from the car package. You can check the code for that function at https://github.com/cran/car/blob/master/R/Anova.R

I wish I could be of more help, but I'm no expert on this topic. I think all the bibliography I have specified could be of help. Now I truly encourage you to check the question as answered as this has been a really big effort and, as I said, StackOverflow is not the place to receive extremely detailed math advice.

Comment: I have added references to specific pages on Howell's excellent book. Good luck with your research (and if you find a better reference, don't forget to post it, as it will be of help for anybody else that has this doubt).